# How to assign a column name to an element in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried following code for this simple, very basic task:

```
dd = data.frame("a","b")
dd
#   X.a. X.b.
# 1    a    b

dd2 = data.frame("","")
dd2
#   X.. X...1
# 1          

names(dd)[1]
# [1] "X.a."

dd2[1,1] <- names(dd)[1]
# Warning message:
# In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "X.a.") :
#   invalid factor level, NAs generated

dd2
#    X.. X...1
# 1 <NA>
```

Why only "`NA`" is entered at [1,1] of dd2 ? How can I correct this error?

Comment: you need either character columns or need to add the new levels to your factor columns; if you don't know what that means, read `?factor` and also see `stringsAsFactors` in `?data.frame`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You only showed what you tried so far. Your code seems odd. Besides figuring what's wrong in the code above, we could suggest alternative methods of accomplishing what you want.

Comment: I was just trying data manipulation in R. "dd2$A = as.character(dd2$A)" command changes column to character column, after which I can assign it any text value. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a `character` value to a data.frame it is converted to a `factor`, which can only take limited values.

Use this to avoid this behavior

```
dd2 = data.frame("","", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

You should be able to change it to anything you want.

Comment: It still give same error message. A third column with colName 'as.is' is created and its first row contains 'TRUE'

Comment: @rnso, I *think* that ilir meant to write `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as suggested by eddi in the comments.

Comment: @AnandaMahto that's indeed what I meant. I thought the `as.is` argument applied here too, but I was wrong. Correcting the answer.